# .resize get triggered on divs?

Tags: jquery, resize, height

I have something like this:

```
<div id="container">
 <img src="" id="bigImg">
</div>
```

On the page there are thumbs and when you click on them the `#bigImg` change (depedning on the thumbs)

Now I would like to prevent the `#container` to get smaller in the case you switch from a big image to a small image.

I tried something like this, but the event when i change the `#bigImg.src` doenst' get triggered

```
$('#container').resize(function(){
    alert($(this).height());
});
```

Comment: i don't think divs have resize event.. i would try something like `$('#bigImg').load(function(){alert($(this).parent().height())})`

Comment: i have posted another question with another point of view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384091/why-changing-src-of-an-image-is-async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does in IE (8 at least) but not in Firefox or Chrome, cant say for any others.

Ive setup a timer to check the offsetsizes periodically to perform my own onresize functionality, works for what I needed (divs may resize in my apps independently of the page )

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, jQuery resize works for window element : http://api.jquery.com/resize/

You can try this : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/