# Why changing src of an image is async?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have somethign like this:

```
<div id="container">
 <img id="screenFirstImg">
</div>
```

And js:

```
$('a.screenThumbLink').click(function(){

  console.log( $('#container').height() );
    $('img.screenFirstImg').attr('src','new src');
  console.log( $('#container').height() );

});
```

Basically on the click of a tumbnail the `screenFirstImage` get changed (with a bigger image). But console.log shows the exact same number of the height and that's not possibile because after i set the new src the container gets bigger.

Maybe thats because when i do teh second console.log the image hasn't loaded yet.
How can I get the .height after the loading of the img?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#container img").load(function () {
  console.log( $("#container").height() );
});

$('a.screenThumbLink').click(function(){
  $('img.screenFirstImg').attr('src','new src');
});
```

Comment: @yes123 Yes. It's the documentation for [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). You are probably confusing it with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
$('a.screenThumbLink').click(function(){

  console.log( $('#container').height() );
  $('img.screenFirstImg')
      .one('load', function(){
               console.log( $('#container').height() );
          })
      .attr('src','new src');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

attach an onload event to the image, that will fire when then image has been loaded and you can do whatever you need then.